# Why are connective spectra called "connective"?

Tags: terminology, at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Recall that a spectrum is called connective if it is $(-1)$-connected (that is, its homotopy is concentrated in nonnegative degrees).

However, this left me scratching my head a bit.  Why "connective"?  Is there some geometric intuition behind it that I'm missing?

Comment: Do mean to say a non-empty spectrum? Because (-1)-connected could be construed as saying $\pi_{-1}(X)$ is inhabited. 

More seriously, perhaps it is because the delooping of the spectrum is connected....

Comment: I wasn't aware that the empty spectrum is a spectrum at all. What with the individual components being pointed and all...

Comment: Maybe just because (-1)-connected is a mouthful?  And connected would not be the right term, since that would imply trivial $\pi_0$.  Other than that, I don't know.  Possibly a better question is: where did the term originate?  I have no idea.

Comment: @Dan: Yes, that was part of the implied question.

Comment: @Harry - you got me :)

Comment: I vote for Dan Ramras' to be the correct answer.

Comment: There is no ''empty spectrum''; the empty set is not pointed.

Comment: @Johannes: My comment above was _completely_ free of sarcasm. ;)

Comment: It is possible, even inevitable at times, to introduce a category of "unbased spectra". This is where the suspension spectra of unbased spaces live. The suspension spectrum of the empty space is the initial object, but I probably wouldn't call it empty.

Comment: @Tom: I see how one would construct such a category, but I don't see why would one want to do so.  

Comment: It's a pretty trivial thing, but it does come up naturally in some things I think about. There are several equivalent constructions (which one are you thinking of?), and it's interesting to note that they're equivalent. I sometimes think of spectrum vs unbased spectrum (also of category of spectra vs category of unbased spectra) as analogous to vector spaces vs affine spaces.

Comment: Thanks Tom, for that little bit of redeeming evidence :)

Comment: My pleasure. I never miss a chance to talk about the empty set.

Comment: Boardman and Vogt define a connective cohomology theory on page 1122 of their 1968 BAMS announcement of their delooping machine. They say it is one whose coefficient groups vanish for $n > 0$. Is this the earliest usage?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Maybe just because (-1)-connected is a mouthful? And connected would not be the right term, since that would imply trivial $\pi_0$. Other than that, I don't know.

Comment: For spaces, $k$-connected has come to mean having trivial $\pi_j$ for $j\le k$ (basically -- let's ignore basepoint issues). In hindsight it might have been better to have a term for having trivial $\pi_j$ for $j<k$. Likewise for spectra. Not that "minus one" takes that much longer to say than "zero" ... 